# Link two elements, store them, and send them to remove function - Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a little Pure Javascript prototype demonstrating shopping cart functionality.

I have a Button which adds the item to the cart (and toggles to an ON state) and then a Card which represents the item in the shopping cart.

So far I have worked;

- Attach data to Add to Cart Button ✓
- Send data from Button to Shopping Cart and create new Item Card ✓

However, I cannot work out how to link Button and newly created Item Card so I can:

- Remove Item Card and toggle button OFF or
- Toggle button OFF and remove the correct Item Card

https://codepen.io/rhysyg03/pen/PdyyWE

Your help would be much appreciated.

FYI - this is just for a demo so it doesn't need to be production ready code.

Thank you.

```
const shoppingCartEl = document.querySelector('#js-shopping-cart');
const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('#js-add-to-cart');
var buttonToggle = false;
var itemOneData = {
    name:'Shoes',
    price:"$105.00"
}

function addItem(button, itemData) {
  console.log("ADD");
  // var itemEl = createElement('<div class="item-card"></div>');
  const itemEl = document.createElement("div");
  itemEl.classList.add("item-card");
  itemEl.innerHTML = itemData.name + itemData.price + "<button id='js-item-cart-remove'>Remove</button>";
  shoppingCartEl.appendChild(itemEl);
  const itemCardRemove = document.querySelector('#js-item-cart-remove');
  itemCardRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeItem();
  })
}

function removeItem() {
  console.log("REMOVE");
  // how to do this part
}

addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (buttonToggle == false) {
      addItem(addToCartButton, itemOneData);
      buttonToggle = true;
      addToCartButton.innerHTML = "Remove from Cart";
    } else {
      // How to do this part
      removeItem();
      buttonToggle = false;
      addToCartButton.innerHTML = "Add to Cart";
    }
})
```

Comment: Too broad, no code, too hard to answer

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev No probs, here's a pen. It's setup a bit nicer with classes and partials in the actual prototype but you should get the idea. https://codepen.io/rhysyg03/pen/PdyyWE

Comment: Well, I honestly have spent about 15 minutes, and my stress levels are started to rise above levels I don't want to have. Why? Because the code you wrote is very, very impractical, unmaintainable etc. People used to write like this like 5-10 years ago. You supposed to use frameworks or libraries like Vue.js (better for newbies and overall) and React nowadays. I STRONGLY recommend you to use them.

Comment: What I've started but never finished, if you still want the concept of solution, i'll place to answer below, because it'll have some code

Comment: Yeah agreed React or a better framework are the way to go, but it's big overkill for this purpose. The main purpose is to showcase designs/interactions to developers, something like the Material Design team do here. https://material-components-web.appspot.com/menu.html. I stated it didn't have to be production code.

Comment: Frameworks aren't a catch all solution to every problem you may encounter. Also for learners it may hinder your ability to trouble shoot fundamental problems.

Answer (score 1):

(I am sorry I am tired a bit, you should read the very ending, firstly)

You should have items like this:

```
var itemOneData = {
    id: 1,
    name:'Shoes',
    price:"$105.00"
}

var itemTwoData = {
    id: 2,
    name:'Shoes',
    price:"$105.00"
}
```

Then you should store identifier on the item card element:

```
...
itemEl.classList.add("item-card");
itemEl.setAttribute("data-item-id", itemData.id)
...
```

After this, when clicking on remove button, you should:

1. Get the `id` of item to be removed `itemEl.getAttribute("data-item-id")`
2. Pass the `id` to remove function `removeItem(id)`
3. (this was where I've given up) Find the item with the attribute "data-item-id" having value of the `id` and replace it to empty string ""

There is another solution, probably far less complex: when clicking on remove button simply find it's parent and replace it with empty string.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I managed to use something similar by giving both the button and new create item card the same ID, and then do the magic from there.

Comment: I am glad you solved this! Good luck! Its okay solution by the way (for the demo purposes)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution, just to get what you are looking for, but of course, maybe you should be having some 'state' where you have your cart items, and render the UI based on that state. In this quick solution, what I am doing is event delegation, as we know that the one element that will exist at the beginning is the cart div. So we place the event on this element and then check which element are we clicking, and also doing some check so we assure only that an item-card can be deleted. codepen.io/anon/pen/WgaYxe?editors=1011

Hope this helps and if you need more details please feel free to ask!
Bye

Comment: Thanks @Maxi. I can remove the Cart item with no troubles, it's more about communicating that back to the Add to Cart Button which is in the ON state. And visa versa.

Comment: Glad it helped!